# error while creating aks kubernetes cluster using azure devops : Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: Code="QuotaExceeded"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Trying to create a Kubernetes Cluster using Terraform and azurerm provider . But while doing that I am getting the below error:

> Error: creating Managed Kubernetes Cluster "k8stest_dev" (Resource
> Group "kubernetes_dev"):
> containerservice.ManagedClustersClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending
> request: StatusCode=400 --
>
> Original Error: Code="QuotaExceeded" Message="Provisioning of
> resource(s) for container service k8stest_dev in resource group
> kubernetes_dev failed.
>
> Message: Operation could not be completed as it results in exceeding
> approved standardDSv3Family Cores quota. Additional details -
> Deployment Model: Resource Manager, Location: centralus, Current
> Limit: 4, Current Usage: 0, Additional Required: 6, (Minimum) New
> Limit Required: 6.
>
> Submit a request for Quota increase

Comment: The issue is that you are using standardDSv3 family  and you have 4 cores available for that family in that region . so you will need to raise a quota request or try creating some other family vm's with less core . you can refer [quota increase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/per-vm-quota-requests#:~:text=Azure%20Request%20Quota%20Increase%201%20In%20the%20Azure,select%20Compute-VM%20%28cores-vCPUs%29%20subscription%20limit%20increases.%20See%20More.)

Comment: thanks issue fixed . I changed vm family size and it works .

Comment: Glad to be of help :) will post the same as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `standardDSv3` family and you have 4 cores available for that family in the region you are trying to deploy.

So, For solution , you will need to ***raise a quota request*** or t***ry creating some other family vm's with less core*** .

Reference:

> You can refer this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/per-vm-quota-requests#:%7E:text=Azure%20Request%20Quota%20Increase%201%20In%20the%20Azure,select%20Compute-VM%20%28cores-vCPUs%29%20subscription%20limit%20increases.%20See%20More.) to know about how to
> raise quota increase .
>
> You can refer this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/sizes) for the available VM
> Sizes.